# Column not iterable, PySpark

Tags: vector, pyspark, nlp, vectorization, countvectorizer

I'm trying to perform a count vectorization using this function I've created however, I keep having an error returned stating "column not iterable" which I cannot figure out why and how to resolve it.

(dfNew is the data frame with just two of the columns, both of StringType)

```
import string
import re
import nltk
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
ps = PorterStemmer()

dfNew = df.select(F.col('Description'), F.col('ID'))

def clean_description(text):
        text = "".join([word.lower() for word in text if word not in string.punctuation])
        text = re.sub('[\n\r]+', ' ', text).lower()
        Description = re.split('\W+', text)
        text = [ps.stem(word) for word in Description if word not in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]
        more_stop_words = ['please', 'search', 'submitted', 'thank', 'search', 'com', 'url', 'https', 'via', 'www']
        text = [ps.stem(word) for word in Description if word not in more_stop_words]
        return text

count_vectorize = CountVectorizer(analyzer=clean_description) 
vectorized = count_vectorize.fit_transform(dfNew['Description'])
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can this be resolved?

Comment: `CountVectorizer.fit_transform` may not accept Spark column as input. This method accepts iterables, while Spark column is not.

Comment: @ZygD noted, thank you. I've tried converting the df to an iterator but that doesn't seem to have worked either